# What format of path should be used for savefig?

Tags: python, path, seaborn

I created a path variable for my project using
`proj_path = pathlib.Path('C:/users/data/lives/here')`

I now want to save a seaborn plot as png so I created a new path variable for the file
`plot_path = proj_path.joinpath('plot_name.png')`

but when I call `plot_name.savefig(plot_path)` returns
`TypeError: Object does not appear to be a 8-bit string path or a Python file-like object`

What path format is accepted by savefig and how do I convert plot_path?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use
`plot_name.savefig(plot_path)`
instead of 
`plot_name.savefig('plot_path')` (note no **'**-s).

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my question, not in my actual code. Just edited the question to fix it.